# Is it possible with Flask-SQLAlchemy join to select all columns from one table and specify some from another?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a join of two tables and want to select all the columns from one and only some from another. I feel like I'm close, but it's not quite returning what I want. I have an advertisement table and a coupon table in where they have a 1 to 1 relationship.

I have called a query on the db model like so:

```
result = Advertisement.query.join(Coupon, 
Advertisement.id==Coupon.id).filter(Advertisement.date==Coupon.date, 
Advertisement.id==12345).add_columns(Coupon.discount, 
Coupon.expiry_date)
```

What I want to get back is all the columns from Advertisement and the two from Coupon. My understanding was that add_columns would do this, but I only get back the two from Coupon and nothing from Advertisement. While if I remove add_columns I get back all from Advertisement but nothing from Coupon.

Do I have to declare the table relationship in the class? I know what the query should look like in sql, but I'm at a bit of a loss here. If the information I gave isn't clear enough, let me know and I can try to elaborate further, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
result = session.query(Advertisement, Coupon.discount, Coupon.expiry_date).filter(
   Advertisement.id==Coupon.id, 
   Advertisement.date==Coupon.date, 
   Advertisement.id==12345
)
```

Comment: sorry, where is the `session` variable coming from?

Comment: @marc
```from sqlalchemy.orm import Session  
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql://{pg_user}:{pg_pwd}@{pg_host}:{pg_port}/{pg_db}")  
with Session(engine) as session:
     ....
```